# How to for-each over JSON objects located in the same place?

Tags: javascript, html, json, file, for-loop

I am working with a single JSON object. It looks like:

```
Object --> text --> body --> div Array[20] --> 0
Object --> text --> body --> div Array[20] --> 1
Object --> text --> body --> div Array[20] --> ...
Object --> text --> body --> div Array[20] --> 20
```

So I know how to get to the point where the 20 values are stored. Objectname.text.body.div... but I want to be able to loop over all values, regardless of the size. I don't want to have to hardcode all 20. How do I loop over all these values? Native JS or jQuery solutions would work.

Comment: And that's not JSON, or something we can read?

Comment: Can you show us the actual object and not this visual nonsense?

Comment: You are dealing with a JavaScript object. JSON is never an object, JSON is always a string.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't want to copy paste the whole load of JSON into it. That's what the JSON looks like anyway. The question got answered anyway.

Comment: You are on a coding site. There is no excuse for not showing your code. It doesn't even make sense if you want answers that are more than a "best guess". You're not helping anyone by hiding the very details that are necessary to understand your question.

Comment: Funny you couldn't come up with a for loop... What have you actually tried? :)

Comment: I did try a for loop, just my way wasn't working. Save the ego. And that is the structure of the JSON, it's close enough. Anyone who's seen JSON would know. And the 1 answer someone left worked for me.

Comment: @eltigre you're right, putting a large object in your post is unnecessary, but that doesn't mean you can't find a middle ground. show us the object, and instead of 20 items just write "20 items here". We will understand it better than any textual description or visualization. I'm happy someone managed to help you anyway, good luck and welcome to SO!

Comment: I will keep that in mind for when I ask questions in the future. Thanks yuvi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Objectname.text.body.div.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});
```

Does it help?

Comment: Holy hell, thank you!!! I didn't think it'd look that clean. I'll accept your answer once it lets me.